# Tensorflow cannot dlopen libcudnn

Tags: tensorflow

I am attempting to get GPU training working in Tensorflow 2.4.1. I am running Ubuntu 20.04, with Nvidia driver 460.32.03. I have installed CUDA toolkit 11.2, and cudnn8. When starting tensorflow, this is what I see:

```
2021-01-21 16:23:31.457304: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-01-21 16:23:33.535844: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-01-21 16:23:33.536650: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2021-01-21 16:23:33.566101: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:21:00.0 name: Quadro RTX 4000 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.545GHz coreCount: 36 deviceMemorySize: 7.79GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 387.49GiB/s
2021-01-21 16:23:33.566157: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-01-21 16:23:33.571082: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
2021-01-21 16:23:33.571162: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11
2021-01-21 16:23:33.588669: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-01-21 16:23:33.590407: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-01-21 16:23:33.592191: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2021-01-21 16:23:33.592668: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.11
2021-01-21 16:23:33.592781: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.8'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-01-21 16:23:33.592790: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1757] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
```

`nvidia-smi` looks good:

```
Thu Jan 21 16:31:51 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.32.03    Driver Version: 460.32.03    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro RTX 4000     Off  | 00000000:21:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 30%   36C    P8    11W / 125W |    570MiB /  7979MiB |      3%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      3089      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 71MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4021      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                216MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4153      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              106MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4641      G   ...gAAAAAAAAA --shared-files       29MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4827      G   /usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rstudio      132MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have verified that `libcudnn.so.8` is present in the same folder as the other CUDA libraries:

```
/usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64$ ls -la libcud*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     845076 Jan 21 15:47 libcudadevrt.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         17 Jan 21 15:47 libcudart.so -> libcudart.so.11.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         20 Jan 21 15:47 libcudart.so.11.0 -> libcudart.so.11.2.72
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     582008 Jan 21 15:47 libcudart.so.11.2.72
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     906670 Jan 21 15:47 libcudart_static.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         23 Jan 21 16:19 libcudnn_adv_infer.so -> libcudnn_adv_infer.so.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         27 Jan 21 16:19 libcudnn_adv_infer.so.8 -> libcudnn_adv_infer.so.8.0.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  144525080 Jan 21 16:19 libcudnn_adv_infer.so.8.0.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         23 Jan 21 16:19 libcudnn_adv_train.so -> libcudnn_adv_train.so.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         27 Jan 21 16:19 libcudnn_adv_train.so.8 -> libcudnn_adv_train.so.8.0.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   94896760 Jan 21 16:19 libcudnn_adv_train.so.8.0.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         23 Jan 21 16:19 libcudnn_cnn_infer.so -> libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         27 Jan 21 16:19 libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8 -> libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8.0.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1438587968 Jan 21 16:19 libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8.0.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         23 Jan 21 16:19 libcudnn_cnn_train.so -> libcudnn_cnn_train.so.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         27 Jan 21 16:19 libcudnn_cnn_train.so.8 -> libcudnn_cnn_train.so.8.0.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   89274264 Jan 21 16:19 libcudnn_cnn_train.so.8.0.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         23 Jan 21 16:19 libcudnn_ops_infer.so -> libcudnn_ops_infer.so.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         27 Jan 21 16:19 libcudnn_ops_infer.so.8 -> libcudnn_ops_infer.so.8.0.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  333101688 Jan 21 16:19 libcudnn_ops_infer.so.8.0.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         23 Jan 21 16:19 libcudnn_ops_train.so -> libcudnn_ops_train.so.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         27 Jan 21 16:19 libcudnn_ops_train.so.8 -> libcudnn_ops_train.so.8.0.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   37388984 Jan 21 16:19 libcudnn_ops_train.so.8.0.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         13 Jan 21 16:19 libcudnn.so -> libcudnn.so.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         17 Jan 21 16:19 libcudnn.so.8 -> libcudnn.so.8.0.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     158264 Jan 21 16:19 libcudnn.so.8.0.5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2428480120 Jan 21 16:19 libcudnn_static.a
```

And the library appears to load OK and is not missing any dependencies itself:

```
$ ldd libcudnn.so.8
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe41739000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f652d78a000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f652d767000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f652d761000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f652d580000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f652d565000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f652d371000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f652d9db000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f652d222000)
```

What else could I be missing?

Comment: Please read the output of Tensorflow again. You can see that it is loading CUDA 11.0 from somewhere (not the 11.2 which you installed, that isn't even suported). The correct CUDNN is not located in that somewhere. Put it in that somewhere. And make sure that the CUDNN you do is have is the version for CUDA 11.0

Comment: If you read the rest of my question, you’ll see 11.0 is linked to 11.2. There is no other copy. This is as Nvidia installs it.

Comment: I read it `library libcudart.so.11.0` is the CUDA 11.0 runtime library, not 11.2. IF you don't want to believe me, fine, but until you solve that, nothing works. Best of luck

Comment: OK, I humored you and nuked 11.2, installed 11.0, and reinstalled cudnn 8. Same error.

Comment: It seems the cuda-11 ld.so.conf was missing. I have no idea how it was resolving the first few libraries without it, but after fixing that and running `ldconfig` things are working again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, after some try/fail, I found my fix. The fix is to add this path to the PATH variable by executing:

```
$ export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.4/lib64\
                         ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

this is section 9.1.1 of the CUDA set up (https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#environment-setup)